# Как работает if и else?

Tags: java, android, if

В приложении есть чекбокс, и если пользователь устанавливает галочку то мы должны считать цену чашки кофе не по 5$, а по 6$.

Как это сделать?

if и else вообще не могу дать ладу, знаю как они устроены, НО не знаю куда их впихнуть и что в них писать.

```
public boolean flajok (View view) {
    /** Получаем флажок*/
    CheckBox kopiruem = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chek);
    /**Получаем, отмечен ли данный флажок*/
    boolean uznaem = kopiruem.isChecked();
    return uznaem;
}

/** Кнопка отображающая на экран сумму заказа*/
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int save = calculatePrice(quantity);
    displayMessage(stroke);
}

/** quantity это число чашек кофе, а 5 это цена за чашку*/
public int calculatePrice(int quantity) {
    int pricen = quantity * 5;
    return pricen;
}
```

Comment: Попробую помочь :)  В `calculatePrice` замените код на следующий: `CheckBox kopiruem = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chek);` `int price = kopiruem.isChecked() ? 5 : 6;` `return quantity * price;` . К сожалению, в комментариях нельзя нормально код показывать, поэтому только так

Comment: `if` - это истина, `else` - это ложь, от суда вывод: если в `if` условие(я) равны `true`, то `if` блок отработает, а `else` не отработает..

Comment: gil9red т.е для чекбокса можно не создавать отъдельный метод а прописывать таким образом в любом нужном нам методе где нужно использовать if и else ?

Answer (score 3):

```
/** quantity это число чашек кофе, а 5 это цена за чашку*/

    if(flajok) //проверяем, стоит ли галочка
       return quantity * 6; //если стоит, возвр. знач. * 6

    return quantity * 5; // если не стоит, возвр. знач. * 5
}
```

Или by [Pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff):

```
public int calculatePrice(int quantity) {
   return quantity * (flajok)? 6:5;
}
```

Comment: рекомендуется избегать нескольких точек выхода. Можно сделать как то так через тернарный оператор: `return quantity * (flajok)? 6:5;`

Comment: @pavlofff почему?

Answer (score 0):

Установите слушателя на `Checkbox` у в нем реализуйте условие, если бокс кликнут, выполняете нужный код.

```
CheckBox kopiruem = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chek);
kopituem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
            // Условие если бокс будет кликнут. И выполняете нужные операции
            }
        }
    });
```